# How to "automate" Xcode instruments to catch non-allocating (persistent) objects?

Tags: xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks, profiling, allocation

Would anyone know if it’s possible to "automate" Xcode instruments to catch non-allocating (persistent) objects?[image]

I caught this issue using the “leaks” tool, but now I would like to automate it if possible.